# radio button form submission?

Tags: javascript, html

All.

I've got what should be a simple radio button form, which can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ud62qyow/1/) (Jsfiddle). All I want to achieve is to find out which button is active when myFunction() is ran. Can anybody give a hint? I can't figure out what the issue is.

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var answer1a = (document.getElementById("a1a").checked);
    var answer1b = (document.getElementById("a1b").checked);
    var answer1c = (document.getElementById("a1c").checked);
    var answer1d = (document.getElementById("a1d").checked);
    var answer1e = (document.getElementById("a1e").checked);
    var answer1f = (document.getElementById("a1f").checked);
    var answer1g = (document.getElementById("a1g").checked);
    var answer1h = (document.getElementById("a1h").checked);
    var answer1i = (document.getElementById("a1i").checked);
    var answer1j = (document.getElementById("a1j").checked);

    if answer1a === true {
    alert('Its \'Earlier\'')
    } else if answer1b === true {
    alert('Its \'5AM\'')
    } else if answer1c === true {
    alert('Its \'6AM\'')
    } else if answer1d === true {
    alert('Its \'7AM\'')
    } else if answer1e === true {
    alert('Its \'8AM\'')
    } else if answer1f === true {
    alert('Its \'9AM\'')
    } else if answer1g === true {
    alert('Its \'10AM\'')
    } else if answer1h === true {
    alert('Its \'11AM\'')
    } else if answer1i === true {
    alert('Its \'12PM\'')
    } else if answer1j === true {
    alert('Its \'Later\'')
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form id="q1" method="post">
<p>What time did you wake up?</p>
<!--<input type="text" placeholder="7:00AM" id="a1" />-->
<p>Earlier</p><input type="radio" value="Earlier" id="a1a" name="a1"/>
<p>5:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="5AM" id="a1b" name="a1"/>
<p>6:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="6AM" id="a1c" name="a1"/>
<p>7:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="7AM" id="a1d" name="a1"/>
<p>8:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="8AM" id="a1e" name="a1"/>
<p>9:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="9AM" id="a1f" name="a1"/>
<p>10:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="10AM" id="a1g" name="a1"/>
<p>11:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="11AM" id="a1h" name="a1"/>
<p>12:00PM</p><input type="radio" value="12PM" id="a1i" name="a1"/>
<p>Later</p><input type="radio" value="Later" id="a1j" name="a1"/>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="myFunction"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is exactly why JQuery was developed...

Comment: You are missing brackets. `if (answer1a) {` - also you are not submitting using the button or the radio. - to submit you need to add an onclick handler to the buttons

Comment: Vote to close: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting." - if you hit F12 the console will point to invalid JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problems with your JavaScript Syntax.

Missing brackets around the if statements and unnecessary brackets around the document.getElementById statements

```js
var myFunction = function() {
        var answer1a = document.getElementById("a1a").checked;
        var answer1b = document.getElementById("a1b").checked;
        var answer1c = document.getElementById("a1c").checked;
        var answer1d = document.getElementById("a1d").checked;
        var answer1e = document.getElementById("a1e").checked;
        var answer1f = document.getElementById("a1f").checked;
        var answer1g = document.getElementById("a1g").checked;
        var answer1h = document.getElementById("a1h").checked;
        var answer1i = document.getElementById("a1i").checked;
        var answer1j = document.getElementById("a1j").checked;
        
        if (answer1a) {
        alert('Its Earlier');
        } else if (answer1b) {
        alert('Its 5AM');
        } else if (answer1c) {
        alert('Its 6AM');
        } else if (answer1d) {
        alert('Its 7AM');
        } else if (answer1e) {
        alert('Its 8AM');
        } else if (answer1f) {
        alert('Its 9AM');
        } else if (answer1g) {
        alert('Its 10AM');
        } else if (answer1h) {
        alert('Its 11AM');
        } else if (answer1i) {
        alert('Its 12PM');
        } else if (answer1j) {
        alert('Its Later');
        }
};
```

```html
<form id="q1" method="post">
<p>What time did you wake up?</p>
<!--<input type="text" placeholder="7:00AM" id="a1" />-->
<p>Earlier</p><input type="radio" value="Earlier" id="a1a" name="a1"/>
<p>5:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="5AM" id="a1b" name="a1"/>
<p>6:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="6AM" id="a1c" name="a1"/>
<p>7:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="7AM" id="a1d" name="a1"/>
<p>8:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="8AM" id="a1e" name="a1"/>
<p>9:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="9AM" id="a1f" name="a1"/>
<p>10:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="10AM" id="a1g" name="a1"/>
<p>11:00AM</p><input type="radio" value="11AM" id="a1h" name="a1"/>
<p>12:00PM</p><input type="radio" value="12PM" id="a1i" name="a1"/>
<p>Later</p><input type="radio" value="Later" id="a1j" name="a1"/>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="myFunction"/>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I was busy correcting the code and didn't see that you had already answered.

Comment: When I had seen this question. no one had commented. So I had taken the code to JSfiddle to correct it. When I posted it here, it was too late.

Comment: Rightly correctly. I appreciate your efforts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the missing brackets around the if statement `if (answer1a) {`

For a shorter method you can use `document.querySelector('input[name="a1"]:checked').value` to find the selected radio button

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkValue = document.querySelector('input[name="a1"]:checked').value;
  alert(checkValue)
}
```

```html
<form id="q1" method="post">
  <p>What time did you wake up?</p>
  <!--<input type="text" placeholder="7:00AM" id="a1" />-->
  <p>Earlier</p>
  <input type="radio" value="Earlier" id="a1a" name="a1" />
  <p>5:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="5AM" id="a1b" name="a1" />
  <p>6:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="6AM" id="a1c" name="a1" />
  <p>7:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="7AM" id="a1d" name="a1" />
  <p>8:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="8AM" id="a1e" name="a1" />
  <p>9:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="9AM" id="a1f" name="a1" />
  <p>10:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="10AM" id="a1g" name="a1" />
  <p>11:00AM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="11AM" id="a1h" name="a1" />
  <p>12:00PM</p>
  <input type="radio" value="12PM" id="a1i" name="a1" />
  <p>Later</p>
  <input type="radio" value="Later" id="a1j" name="a1" />
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="myFunction">
```

Comment: I think I am answering to this question **_All I want to achieve is to find out which button is active when myFunction() is ran_**

Comment: I fixed your answer and voted up since the alternative is good - but the question could still be typo closed

Answer (score -1):

Like mentioned before, jQuery is really the way to simplify your code and have it work on older browsers.  Your same concept but cleaned up and simplified with a small jQuery call.

The idea is find the checked check box by using a simple query.  If a checkbox wasn't checked, alert the user.

```js
/* Move the logic out of the page */
$(function(){

  // Wait till it's clicked
  $('#checkButton').click(function(){
    // Find the value, if there is one
    var value = $('input[name=a1]:checked').val();
    // Validate that they choose something
    if (value) {
      // You would do your work here with value
      console.log(value);
    } else {
      // Alert the user to their mistake
      alert('Please make a selection');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="q1" method="post">
<p>What time did you wake up?</p>
<!--<input type="text" placeholder="7:00AM" id="a1" />-->
<p>Earlier<input type="radio" value="Earlier" id="a1a" name="a1"/></p>
<p>5:00AM<input type="radio" value="5AM" id="a1b" name="a1"/></p>
<p>6:00AM<input type="radio" value="6AM" id="a1c" name="a1"/></p>
<p>7:00AM<input type="radio" value="7AM" id="a1d" name="a1"/></p>
<p>8:00AM<input type="radio" value="8AM" id="a1e" name="a1"/></p>
<p>9:00AM<input type="radio" value="9AM" id="a1f" name="a1"/></p>
<p>10:00AM<input type="radio" value="10AM" id="a1g" name="a1"/></p>
<p>11:00AM<input type="radio" value="11AM" id="a1h" name="a1"/></p>
<p>12:00PM<input type="radio" value="12PM" id="a1i" name="a1"/></p>
<p>Later<input type="radio" value="Later" id="a1j" name="a1"/></p>
</form>
<input type="button" id="checkButton" value="myFunction"/>
```

Comment: jQuery is not at all needed here. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43828503/295783

Comment: Identical logic can be implemented using plain javascript with about the same amount of code.

Comment: Never code to plain JavaScript, always use a middle man utility to handle browser inconsistencies.